# Postman: can't find interceptor button

Tags: api, postman

I have installed [Chrome Postman Interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en).

Now when I open Postman, I don't see the interceptor icon on the Postman app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now (see the date) Postman only has support of interceptor in the chrome version, not the desktop. For further info see their [github issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-chrome-interceptor/issues/56#issuecomment-306109230)

Answer (score 12):

Click "Capture requests" in footer of Postman desktop app.
[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. That icon is so small, did not even notice it there!

Comment: The postman documentation is shockingly out of date... so thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As on  v9.24.2, the satellite icon for `Capture requests` has been removed from the top right of the postman app.

Here is what you need to do to check for the icon.

The homepage of PM does not contain the icon.

1. Go to workspaces
2. Create Workspace
3. Once a workspace is created open the same.
4. On the bottom right of the screen you will see the option `Capture Requests`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue....the original Postman app had no interceptor icon.

I uninstalled Postman. Through Chrome store, I added postman interceptor extension for chrome, which then gave me the option to install other products from the same provider so I installed the Postman app from there.

That version has the interceptor icon!

Comment: I had installed something called "Postman Agent" instead of "Postman" and that was my problem

Answer (score 1):

Click on satellite icon in header (near gear icon ),The documentation in their site is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

This frustrated me too! So a number of things about Postman's interface change if you're signed in. If you haven't signed in yet, the Interceptor button should be in the top-left:
[image: Postman's interceptor button in top-right corner]

But if you have signed in, that button disappears, and instead you have to click "Capture Requests" on the bottom-right:

[image: Capture Requests link in bottom-right corner]

There's a few other changes too. When you're logged in, you can hover over the user profile icon in the History window to see timestamps from when a request was ran. Without being logged in, these timestamps won't show up at all. Also, using Interceptor while being logged in, the requests get grouped together as a "Interceptor debug session", rather than displaying the individually under History.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure you installed the interceptor in chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en

This is what I see in Postman and Chrome after intall both extensions

[image: Postman Interceptor]

Comment: it is already installed still do not see the tab. restarted the app as well. and the inceptor is on as well from the extension